# set focus textboxes onkeypressed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

im writing payment page and there is 4 textbox for credit card number entry and after for digits set focus on another control i did for first textbox my javascript code works well but other textboxes doesnt work...  here is my code...:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Length_txtCardNumber1_Validator() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber1.ClientID %>').value.length = 4) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber2.ClientID %>').focus();
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    }


    function Length_txtCardNumber2_Validator() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber2.ClientID %>').value.length = 4) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber3.ClientID %>').focus();
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    }

    function Length_txtCardNumber3_Validator() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber3.ClientID %>').value.length = 4) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber4.ClientID %>').focus();
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    }
</script>
```

code behind `onpage_load` :

```
txtCardNumber1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return Length_txtCardNumber1_Validator()");
txtCardNumber2.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return Length_txtCardNumber2_Validator()");
txtCardNumber3.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return Length_txtCardNumber3_Validator()");
```

thank you...

Comment: zozo answer should solve your immediate problem, you can improve the code though and make it more "generic" let us know if interested.

Comment: sure id like to... what should i do...

Comment: see my answer. :) By the way use `@` to notify people when you reply in comments otherwise most people won't come back as they won't see you posted it.

Comment: no problem, you can also use the first 3 letters only if you're the lazy type. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have "generic" code without depending on ID or name of the textboxes, plus allowing only digits as a bonus.

First, wrap all textboxes with single container and give them `maxlength` like this:

```
<div id="CreditCardPanel">
    <asp:Textbox id="txtCardNumber1" runat="server" Columns="3" MaxLength="4" /> -
    <asp:Textbox id="txtCardNumber2" runat="server" Columns="3" MaxLength="4" /> -
    <asp:Textbox id="txtCardNumber3" runat="server" Columns="3" MaxLength="4" /> -
    <asp:Textbox id="txtCardNumber4" runat="server" Columns="3" MaxLength="4" />
</div>
```

Now all you have to do is having such JS code and it's all done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrCreditCardInputs = [];
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementById("CreditCardPanel").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oCurInput.type == "text") {
            oCurInput.onkeypress = function(event) {
                //allow digits only:
                var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
                    if (this.value.length + 1 >= this.maxLength) {
                        var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute("arr_index"), 10);
                        var nextIndex = ((index + 1) % arrCreditCardInputs.length);
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            arrCreditCardInputs[nextIndex].focus();
                        }, 200);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            oCurInput.setAttribute("arr_index", i + "");    
            arrCreditCardInputs.push(oCurInput);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically, the code is taking all the textbox elements in the container, and assign their `onkeypress` event so that only digits can be pressed and when reaching the maximum length focus the next textbox as defined in the global array containing them.

Timer is used to allow the browser a chance to change the value of the textbox, otherwise setting focus immediately will "cancel" the key press and the value won't change.

Live test case is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/72VLw/1/), try messing around with the code and understand how it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use == for comparison.

```
function Length_txtCardNumber3_Validator() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber3.ClientID %>').value.length == 4) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtCardNumber4.ClientID %>').focus();
        return (false);
    }
    return (true);
}
```

Comment: thx alot... but if condition doesnt work... focus changes ever single key pressed...

Comment: To fix that you can use onkeyup event on the specified fields instead of you onpage_load code. Should do the trick. <input type="text" onkeyup="Length_etc();" />

Answer (score 0):

I bound the keyup event to the textboxes

```
        $('#ccNumber1').bind('keyup',function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 4)
                $('#ccNumber2').focus();
        });
```